# Is there a phrase that neatly encapsulates wanting to prove yourself when being compared to someone else?

Tags: phrase-requests

I was thinking you might say that "I live in their shadow" but that doesn't cover wanting to prove yourself?

Is there a phrase or expression that covers both? Something about saplings in shade growing taller?

Comment: Probably something related to aspiration.

Comment: Can you say what 'compared to someone else' changes, as opposed to simply 'wanting to prove yourself'?  I think 'compared to…' makes it competitive but is that what you meant?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I think the competitive nature isn't quite what I'm wanting to focus on, I think the kind of comparison is Luffy from One Piece to Shanks, or Hercules from the start of the Disney movie heroes. Those are characters that might have been compared to people who came before them, but I want to emphasis that at least to start with they're overshadowed by their antecedent's achievements but want to surpass them.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Please clarify how 'they're overshadowed by their antecedent's achievements but want to surpass them' is not a text-book definition of competitiveness?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin competitiveness is with *peers* by my estimation, at least usually. If there one you're compared to no longer competes, that can't be competitiveness.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Wanting to surpass (anyone) makes it a competition. Merely wanting to demonstrate one's own prowess doesn't.